# How to build an anaconda environment using jython

Tags: python, anaconda, jython

I am trying to build an Anaconda virtual environment that uses `jython` 2.7. I tried using the command string:

```
conda create -n py27j_jython python=jython
```

but Anaconda said it could not find the package with the following message:

```
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - python jython*
```

Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: where did you find that this should work?

Comment: I was reading a blog post by [jake vanderplas](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/). He said "You could certainly use conda to build a Jython software stack, but each package would require a new Jython-specific installation artifact – that is what is required to maintain the strict dependency chain that conda users rely on." Perhaps I am misinterpreting what he meant by a Jython software stack. Are you saying that this is not possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment.

Comment: Okay, that is fine. Thanks for the tip.